# Как сохранить только что введённые данные из TextAres?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Как можно сохранить в переменную, только что введённые данные из textarea, без сервера, текстового файла и т.п., надо просто чтобы введённые данные остались после обновления страницы, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: сохраняйте в localstorage

Comment: @Konst а могли бы вы показать код?
я не особо силен в JS

Comment: посмотрите эту статью: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код запоминает содержимое пока только при вводе с клавиатуры:

```html
<textarea id=txt></textarea>
<script>
txt.onkeyup = () => localStorage.setItem("myvalue", txt.value);
txt.value = localStorage.getItem("myvalue");
</script>
```