# ка сделать чтобы input сохранял введенные данные(текст) при закрытии сайта. Например как простой блокнот

Tags: javascript, html5

```
    <div class="addContainer">
        <div class="add" onclick=add()>+</div>  
    </div>
    
    <div> <input type="text" id="text" value="" maxlength="30"> </div>
```

Comment: Прочитайте про localStorage.

Comment: как написать js код что когда я ввожу данные в input, моем случае простой текст, то он там сохранялся и оставался и при выходе из сайта, и был там при следующем открытии сайта, то есть не стирался пока я не стираю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сохранить только что введённые данные из TextAres?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1418605/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-textares)